# Way to design a Dialog with 3 rows on iOS - multi language usable

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to create a view (normal Single View) in iOS which contains 3 Labels and 3 Text fields.

The App should be able for multi language use.

I want to have to following layout:

```
Label | TextField
Label | TextField
Label | TextField
```

The TextFields should start at the same position. (see image)

But the lengths of the textfields should dependent on the length of the Text in the Labels.
 (I want to minimize the space, that you can see on the image for the english language.

To put it in a nutshell, the english layout should have the same space between the label and text field as the german one.

What is the best way to do this, using the auto layout?

[image: Image (english), to many space]
[image: Image (german)]

Comment: You may want to consider using a modal view rather than an alertview.

Comment: I want to use a normal view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for each row :
Size the label to fit the text.
Then put in a horizontal spacing between the label and the text field.

Then add a higher priority constraint on the textfields that all left edges should lineup.

Here is some code which does it for two rows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
      [super viewDidLoad];

      //create labels and text fields for row 1
      UILabel *label0,*label1;
      UITextField *textField0,*textField1;

      label0 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
      label0.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
      [self.view addSubview:label0];


      textField0 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
      textField0.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
      [self.view addSubview:textField0];

      [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
      [label0 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
      [textField0 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

      //*************************************************************
      //layout row 1
      NSArray *arr;
      NSDictionary *dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label0,textField0);
      NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;

      //label sized to fit text (default) and standard spacing between label and textField
      arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[label0]-[textField0(100)]"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:dict];
      [self.view addConstraints:arr];

      //vertical constraints
      arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[label0]"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:dict];
      [self.view addConstraints:arr];

      arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[textField0]"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:dict];
      [self.view addConstraints:arr];


      //*************************************************************
      //create label and textfield for row2
      label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
      label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
      [self.view addSubview:label1];

      textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
      textField1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
      [self.view addSubview:textField1];

      [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
      [label1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
      [textField1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

      //*************************************************************
      //layout row 2
      dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label0,textField0,label1,textField1);

      //label sized to fit text (default) and standard spacing between label and textField
      arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[label1]-[textField1(100)]"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:dict];
      [self.view addConstraints:arr];

      //vertical constraints
      arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[label0]-[label1]"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:dict];
      [self.view addConstraints:arr];

      arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[textField0]-[textField1]"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:dict];
      [self.view addConstraints:arr];



      //*************************************************************
      //line up the left edges of the text fields and make it a higher priority to override spacing
      constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField0 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:textField1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
      constraint.priority=UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
      [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

      //*************************************************************
      //Setup some text  
      //label0.text=@"Label0";
      label0.text=@"Some long textasdfasdfadsfasfdasf";
      textField0.text = @"textField0";

      //label1.text=@"Some long text";
      label1.text=@"Label1";
      textField1.text = @"textField1";

      [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: Of note is that he could also specify the same constraints in Interface Builder in a xib...

Comment: I have tried to set this in Interface Builder an it works. Thanks for your help